# Linux user authentication with Microsoft LDAP

Tags: linux, ldap

I'm trying to do following things:

1. Login to CentOS over ssh: authentication needs to happen with Microsoft Ldap
2. On successful login create a home directory for user in /home if directory exists take him to his home directory
3. Put quota on /home/user directory of 5 GB

Can someone please show me a link for Centos/redhat to authorize users with Microsoft Ldap?

I have already tried: setup command from root -> "Authentication configuration" -> "[] User Information -> Use Ldap" -> Authentication -> [] Use Ldap Authentication" -> []/[*] Use TLS -> Server: ldap://corporate.company.com -> Base DN: dc=corporate,dc=company,dc=com" This does not authentication users with Microsoft LDAP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "authenticate linux user against AD" part was extensively covered [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/170274/authenticate-cvs-users-against-active-directory).
 For part 2 of your question you will probably need to put a little script into your /etc/bash.bashrc file (if your users use bash, otherwise you'll need to find out which file is run for that user's particular shell). Same goes for part 3 of your question.

Answer (score 1):

You have to manually edit your ldap.conf file.  MSFT AD requires that a user be authenticated to even lookup a user account in AD.  Create a user account in AD that's just for doing LDAP lookups.

binddn cn=ldap_user,cn=Users,dc=echostar,dc=com
bindpwd secretbinddn cn=ldap_user,cn=Users,dc=company,dc=com
bindpwd password_gones_here

Answer (score 0):

For part 2, you can use [pam_mkhomedir](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/libs/pam/Linux-PAM-html/sag-pam_mkhomedir.html) to automatically create a user's home-directory if it doesn't exist.